# If rank(A) = 3 and rank(B) = 3 for two 3x3 matrices, is it possible for rank(AB) to be less than 3?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Matrices A and B are 3 x 3 matrices, and rank(A) = rank(B) = 3. I understand why rank(AB) can be equal to rank(A) and rank(B), but I don't see how rank(AB) could be less.

Comment: Is the product of two invertible matrices invertible ? And how does rank relates to beeing invertible ?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are 2 bijections from $R^3$ to $R^3$, is there any case where $fog$ is not a bijection from $R^3$ to $R^3$ ?

Answer (score 2):

A $3\times 3$ matrix of rank $3$ is necessarily invertible, and the product of two invertible matrices is invertible and thus of rank $3$.

As for an example of what you're asking for, you can take any nilpotent matrix, for example:

$$N=\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 1\\
0& 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

You see that $\text{rank}(N)=2$ and $\text{rank}(N^2)=1$.